# Want to find the min & max index into a vector with binarySearch

Tags: c++, c++14, binary-search

I've just learned how a binary search works and I need to find the min and max index in a vector. I tried multiple things, but every time my function avoids a part of my code... I have no more ideas, it doesn't seem that difficult but still... I'm struggling a lot with this concept.

EDIT: I realise my explanation were non existant. So what i want to do is, for a given note, i want to find the lowest index of it into a members vector of Song.

heres my closest try :

```
  int Song::binarySearchMin(const Note& note)
{
int Min = 0, Max = notes.size() ,ind=0;
    while (Min <= Max)
    {
        int middle = (Min + Max) / 2;
        if (note == notes[middle])
        {
            ind = middle;
            Max = middle;
            while (Min <= Max)
            {
                middle = (Min + Max) / 2;
                if ((note == notes[middle]) && (middle <= ind))
                {
                    ind = middle;
                }
                Max = middle - 1;
            }
            return ind;
        }
        else if (note < notes[middle])
        {
            Max = middle-1;
        }
        else
        {
            Min = middle +1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I can't figured out why it's not covering every situation. Right now it work when my index is in the middle. But, it c'ant process multiple index.

Comment: Use english names for your variable, that will help non-french community understand their usage ;)

Comment: Oh, indeed thanks it's done.

Comment: If you want to use binary search, you need to sort the data... but if you sort to data, you don't need to search for the min and the max anymore... for a linear search,  just use [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element).

Comment: Is a Song an array of notes? In that case, is the note array sorted? Sounds like a horrible song :)

Comment: JHBonarius, Yes it's supposed to be sort, to be precise all the givem song in this exercise aren't sorted but we have to create one. I think our teacher want us to fully understand the binary search maybe that's why he haven't mentioned this minmax fonction.

Cem, ahah you're right, it's just an horrible list of sorted note, not sure if I want to ear them

Comment: Ok... so think about this again... if the data is sorted, do you _need_ a search to find the minimum and maximum value. Think very hard! Were wil they (always) be located? (P.s. you need to add an @ before my name to tag me)

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know a binary search works on sorted data so I think it's not a good idea to use it on unsorted data , finding min and max in unsorted vector requires a linear search . and a binary search is efficient in finding an element in a sorted array or vector.

Comment: Yes you're right. Our exercise is just for make us understand everything around complexity/sort and binary search. So we had to create a sorted area for this specific question